# Apply a texture on a sphere without showing its edges

Tags: texturing

I am completely new to a 3D software and i was trying to find a solution for this problem for the past few days but nothing is giving me desired effect. Please pardon me if my terminologies are not accurate.
I need to apply a painting on the surface of sphere which have to look seamless. 
I have found a few tutorials in you tube (applying earth map, some textures etc) and I tried it but the seam is there whatever UV mapping i have done. So I thought of making a custom texture with a normal mapping tutorial i found in you tube but i am doubtful if it will do any good to me because of the seams that is continuously appearing after my every try. I am attaching one of the few paintings i have to wrap around sphere here.

Also please advise me which render engine is good for texture exports. I am using Blender 2.79 and when i tried to export an OBJ with cycle render the textures were not exported.

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Arun

[image]

Comment: Is this the actual texture you want to apply to your sphere?
If so, your main problem is that the texture itself is not suitable for seamless texturing, as its pattern is not regular and/or matching on the opposite edges. Google "make image texture seamless" for possible remedies.

Also, this image will (in one way or another) get severely distorted when mapped to a sphere, no matter what projection you use.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to make a possible pattern out of this. But Could you please give me some information about the render engine I mentioned in the question?

Comment: I'm afraid that I have not a lot of experience with exporting textured geometry, which is why I didn't answer initally. Since you asked, I will try but this answer may not be accurate: 
As far as I know, material export should be independent of render engine. If you have your material set up with texture and proper UV map, the export should work. However, it may be necessary to have the texture image in the same directory as the output obj.

Comment: Thank You very much for the information